# Why does the request time recorded by Chrome suddenly become smaller?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[screenshot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXAwl.jpg) (My reputation score is too low to display screenshots directly, I can only use inline links)

When I use JQuery.ajax to get the page content and render the content into the specified dom (pseudo-code:  `$.ajax({url: "/path/indx", success: function(data){$dom.html(data)}})`), the time consumed by request "/index" changed from 68ms to 12ms.

As shown in the [screenshot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXAwl.jpg) (the six parts of the picture are screenshots of different moments of one request):

- screenshot-1: "/index" request is sent and pending
- screenshot-2: "/index" request completed, and then the other two requests sent and pending
- screenshot-3: "xx.app.js" request completed, "xx.app.css" request pending
- screenshot-4: "xx.app.css" request completed; "listHistory" request sent and pending'; the graphs for the three requests are compressed to the left, **and the blue part in the "/index" request disappears**;
- screenshot-5: the time consumed by the "/index" request changed from 68ms to 12ms; but the space between the "/index" request and "xx.app.css" is still there.
- screenshot-6: the "/index" request time-consuming details; (Because the request is too fast, I cannot capture the time-consuming details of screenshot-2)

I want to know why the time taken for "/index" has changed from 68ms to 12ms. Is the original 68ms the estimated time of Google Chrome (version: 98.0.4758.82)?

Other known situations:

- This phenomenon will still occur after disabling Caching.
- **When Performance is enabled for recording, the phenomenon will not occur.**
- When I use "chrome://net-export" to capture the logs, the "/index" request indeed only consumes 12ms

Comment: in-line the screenshot